# Build Context (consumer client) specific spring application

Tags: spring, grails, spring-boot, design-patterns

I am building a spring-boot + grails application using grails 3.3.0 and spring-boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

I have controller serving JSON data to consumer client application.

**ExampleController.groovy**

```
class ExampleCotnroller {

    def endpointServerJosn(){
    }
}
```

Recently one more consumer was introduced and it expects the similar JSON data but from a different source.

So I added a flag to my **application.yml** another.client=true and modified my controller to:

Updated **ExampleController.groovy**

```
class ExampleCotnroller {

    def endpointServerJosn(){
        if(another.client){
            //server data from this client's source
        }else{
            //server data from other client's source
        }
    }
}
```

But I am expecting more set of clients and this going to mess up my controller as I don't find my solution scalable by design. Here each client is having it's own slave API controller to fetch data.

> client 1 sends request -> master (my controller) intercepts, calls one
>   ore more slave APIs related to client, fetches data and aggregates it
>   and sends data back
>
> simiallarly, client 2 sends request -> master (my controllers)
>   intercepts, calls one or more slave APIs related to client 2

I was thinking of having an abstract controller like:

```
class AbstractApplicationController{

        def endpointServerJson();
}

class FirstCilentController extends AbstractApplicationController {
}

class SecondClientController extends AbstractApplicationController {
}
```

Is it possible to achieve a scalable solution with above design? Can application choose which controller to prefer based on config in **external yml** or **application.yml** file?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are describing the problem of `Multitenancy`. From wikipedia:

> The term **"software multitenancy"** refers to a software architecture in which a **single instance of software** runs on a server and **serves multiple** [...] **users** who share a common access with specific privileges to the software instance.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy

I would advise you to start researching the concept of multitenancy at length before implementing any more code. There are plenty of resources out there but this link is a great introduction:

https://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/make-your-spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/

Finally, if indeed you are under dire time constraints. It seems to me like you should create a client agnostic data access layer or set of services underneath your controller that provides methods to retrieve data and accepts the client identifier as an argument. For example:

```
class ExampleCotnroller {

    def endpointServerJosn() {
        return clientDataService.getData(clientID);
    }

}
```